# Алгоритм поиска в неупорядоченном массиве сложностью O(log n)

Tags: алгоритм

Читаю "Алгоритмы: построение и анализ" там есть упражнение

> разработайте алгоритм со временем работы ϴ(n log n), который для
>   заданного множества S из n целых чисел и другого целого числа x
>   определяет имеются ли в множестве S два элемента, сумма которых равна
>   x

Про упорядоченность S ничего не сказано, значит считаем что последовательность не упорядочена.Сломал всю голову, не могу сообразить, если б последовательность была упорядочена, тогда все понятно, перебор + двоичный поиск, а как достичь требуемой сложности алгоритма непонятно

Comment: Сортируем за O(n*log n), дальше - проход по множеству в поисках пары - O(n)... Все, задача решена. Если бы она была изначально упорядочена, хватило бы O(n)

Comment: @Harry, как в данном случаи считать сложность, если O(n log n) это только сортировка, а потом еще O(n), это разве не O((n *log n) + n)?
И кстати интересно как в упорядоченном массиве найти пару за O(n) ?

Comment: А что такое O(n log n + n), как не O(n log n)? :) А как искать? Берем указатель снизу, сверху. Суммируем. Больше x? идем верхним вниз, пока не найдем, или пока не станет меньше. Стало меньше? остановились, идем нижним вверх с примерно таким же условием - но пока не станет больше... И так - пока не встретимся :) При этом пройдем обеими никак не больше n шагов, т.е. O(n).

Comment: с O(n) да, точно, а с "А что такое O(n log n + n), как не O(n log n)?" не понятно почему так, типа потому что вторая n не учитывается?

Comment: Ну прочтите, что такое обозначения  О большого... Потому что предел n/(n log n) при n, стремящемся к бесконечности, равен 0...

Comment: читал, да и в книге про это подробно расписано, настолько подробно, что фиг поймешь (парадокс ☺), скорей всего вы правы, просто это контринтуитивно.

Вот есть алгоритм 1 когда у нас упорядоченный список, у него сложность O(n)
И второй алгоритм с неупорядоченным списком. Второй решаем в 2 шага, шаг 1 сложностью O(n log n) приводит нас к алгоритму 1 который мы так же выполняем, делаем 2 шага, а общая сложность как шагга 1. 
Эт x + y = x получается

Comment: @Артем Артемыч Если к бочке воды прибавить ещё ложку, получится всё равно бочка.

Comment: вот теперь понятно )